# How to benchmark python function with concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I would like to measure the runtime of a service (API) which I can call in parallel.
What is the proper way of benchmarking and using `concurrent.futures` (multiprocessing/multithreading)?

We can `submit()` tasks then once a task is done we can check it with `concurrent.futures.as_completed()` - do we need the `as_completed()` part, as that should return the results for us, the `submit()` just starts the task?

Based on my dummy code it looks like it is not needed, but then why `as_completed()` is not needed? (I thought `submit()` puts the task in a queue, and does not wait for response, and with `as_completed()` you'll get the completed tasks with results).

Let's cal the service `my_job()`:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import time
from typing import List


def _my_job(t: int):
    time.sleep(t)


def measure(N_requ: int, workers: int, wait_time: int, include_as_completed: bool):
    futures = []
    start_time = time.time()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
        for _ in range(N_requ):
            f = executor.submit(_my_job, wait_time)
            futures.append(f)
        if include_as_completed:
            for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                try:
                    _ = f.result()
                except:
                    print("This should not happen...")
                    pass
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time: float = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Elpsed time: {elapsed_time} | n_workers: {workers}, n_requs: {N_requ}, job's wait_time: {wait_time}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 20
    n_workers: List[int] = [1, 4, 16, 32]
    print("Without as_completed:")
    for w in n_workers:
        measure(N, workers=w, wait_time=1, include_as_completed=False)
    print("With as_completed:")
    for w in n_workers:
        measure(N, workers=w, wait_time=1, include_as_completed=True)
```

Results:

```
Without as_completed:
Elpsed time: 20.05830979347229 | n_workers: 1, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1
Elpsed time: 5.012893199920654 | n_workers: 4, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1
Elpsed time: 2.0075199604034424 | n_workers: 16, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1
Elpsed time: 1.0035851001739502 | n_workers: 32, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1

With as_completed:
Elpsed time: 20.044990062713623 | n_workers: 1, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1
Elpsed time: 5.009936809539795 | n_workers: 4, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1
Elpsed time: 2.0069048404693604 | n_workers: 16, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1
Elpsed time: 1.0069079399108887 | n_workers: 32, n_requs: 20, job's wait_time: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the executor as a context manager. At the end of the `with` block, you automatically shut down the executor, *waiting for all pending futures to complete*.

See the docs for [`Executor.shutdown`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown), particularly the part about `with` behavior.